# How would I get tomorrow's day of the month using JS?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the next day's date in Javascript. I can't find anything that will return it like the getDate() function. Thanks!

Comment: You can write your own function to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something like that, called `setDate()`.

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
console.log(date);
```